# No inserta datos a la base de datos desde el modal php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Este es el codigo, probé todas las sentencias sql en el workbench y sí inserta y muestra los datos, pero, al momento de insertar desde el formulario modal, me dice fallo del servidor con el alertify.

No sé qué error podría tener, estoy aprendiendo javascript.

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Tabla Dinamica</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">

    <script src="librerias/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="tabla">
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modaNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar equipo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <label>Nro Orden</label>
        <input type="text" name="id_orden" id="id_orden" class="form-control input-sm">
        <label>Serie</label>
        <input type="text" name="serie_1" id="serie_1" class="form-control input-sm">
             <label>Equipo</label>
             <input type="text" name="equipo_1" id="equipo_1" class="form-control input-sm">
                <label>Cable AV</label>
                <select type="text" name="cable_av_1" id="cable_av_1" class="form-control input-sm">
                   <option value="si">Si</option>
                   <option value="no">No</option>
                </select>  
                       <label>Cable HDMI</label>
                        <select type="text" name="cable_hdmi_1" id="cable_hdmi_1" class="form-control input-sm">
                         <option value="1">Si</option>
                         <option value="2">No</option>
                         </select>

                             <label>Control</label>
                             <select type="text" name="control_1" id="control_1" class="form-control input-sm">
                                     <option value="1">Si</option>
                                     <option value="2">No</option>
                             </select>
                                  <label>Fuente</label>
                                                  <select type="text" name="fuente_1" id="fuente_1" class="form-control input-sm">
                                                   <option value="1">Si</option>
                                                   <option value="2">No</option>
                                                   </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">Agregar</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');

     });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#guardarnuevo').click(function(){
              id_orden=$('#id_orden').val();
              serie_1=$('#serie_1').val();
              equipo_1=$('#equipo_1').val();
              cable_av_1=$('#cable_av_1').val();
              cable_hdmi_1=$('#cable_hdmi_1').val();
              control_1=$('#control_1').val();
              fuente_1=$('#fuente_1').val();
            agregardatos(id_orden, serie_1,equipo_1,cable_av_1,cable_hdmi_1,control_1,fuente_1);
          });
      });
</script>
```

`agregardatos.php` - Acá agrego los datos

```
<?php

    require_once "conexion.php";    
    $conn=conn();
    $id_orden=$_POST['id_orden'];
    $serie_1= $_POST['serie_1'];
    $equipo_1=$_POST['equipo_1'];
    $cable_av_1=$_POST['cable_av_1'];
    $cable_hdmi_1=$_POST['cable_hdmi_1'];
    $control_1=$_POST['control_1'];
    $fuente_1=$_POST['fuente_1'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO ordenes (id_orden,serie_1, equipo_1, cable_av_1, cable_hdmi_1, control_1, fuente_1)
                VALUES ('$id_orden','$serie_1','$equipo_1','$cable_av_1','$cable_hdmi_1','$control_1','$fuente_1')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
```

`funciones.js`

```
function agregardatos(id_orden, serie_1, equipo_1, cable_av_1, cable_hdmi_1, control_1, fuente_1){

      cadena="orden=" + id_orden +
             "&serie=" + serie_1 +
             "&equipo=" + equipo_1 +
             "&cableav=" + cable_av_1 +
             "&cablehdmi=" + cable_hdmi_1 +
             "&control=" + control_1 +
             "&fuente=" + fuente_1;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/agregardatos.php",
        data:cadena,
          success:function(r){
              if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
                  alertify.success("agregado con exito");
              }else{
                  alertify.error("fallo el servidor");
              }

          }
    });

    }
```

`conexion.php`

```
<?php
           function conn(){
               $servidor="localhost";
               $usuario="root";
               $password="";
               $bd="formulario";

               $conn=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd);

               return $conn;
           }
?>
```

`tabla.php`

```
<?php

  require_once "../php/conexion.php";
  $conn=conn();

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Tabla de registros express</h2>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
        <caption>
             <button class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaNuevo">Agregar nuevo
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
             </button>

        </caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Nro Orden</td>
                <td>Serie</td>
                <td>Equipo</td>
                <td>Cable AV</td>
                <td>Cable HDMI</td>
                <td>Control</td>
                <td>Fuente</td>
                <td>Editar</td>
                <td>Eliminar</td>

            </tr>
              <?php
                  $sql="SELECT id_orden,serie_1, equipo_1, cable_av_1, cable_hdmi_1, control_1, fuente_1
                           from ordenes ";

                  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                  while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){


              ?>


            <tr>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[0] ?></td>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[1] ?></td>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[2] ?></td>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[3] ?></td>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[4] ?></td>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[5] ?></td>
               <td><?php  echo $ver[6] ?></td>
               <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion"></button>
               </td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
`
```

Los nombres que tengo en los id y name es como se llama en la base de datos. es mi primer mini proyecto con javascript.

Comment: te recomiendo que leas como preguntar para que las personas puedan tener una idea mas clara de lo que intentas hacer, es necesario mostrar tanto código? saludos

Comment: Deberias poner el error que te da al subscribir el formulario.

Comment: gracias, si recien arranque con stackoverflow!

Comment: Para empezar, `agregardatos.php` no está generando una salida y, según tu javascript, debería devolver `1` en caso de éxito u otro valor en caso de error. Luego, no estás validando los datos recibidos y los colocas directamente en una consulta, te recomiendo pasar por aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php